# How can I increase-decrease the slidesPerView according to the window size of a Swiper slider?

Tags: javascript, slider, swiper.js, bootstrap-cards, angularjs-slider

My motive is when the display size will be small then the `slidesPerView` will be 1. I tried the below way, it's working when I refresh the page. But I want it will work automatically. When the window size will increase automatically the `slidesPerView` will be increased, again when the window size will decrease automatically the `slidesPerView` will be decreased. Where am I doing the mistake? give me a relevant solution...

***swiper.js:***

```
if(window.innerWidth>768){
  var swiper = new Swiper(".productSwiper", {
    slidesPerView: 3,
    spaceBetween: 30
  });
}else{
  var swiper = new Swiper(".productSwiper", {
    slidesPerView: 1
  });
}
```

***index.html:***

```
<div class="swiper productSwiper my-5">
        <div class="swiper-wrapper col-6 col-md-5 col-lg-3">

            <div class="swiper-slide card" style="width: 18rem;">

                <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
                    <img src="static/1_medicine/2.jpg" class="card-img-top product_img d-block py-3" alt="product image 1">
                </div>
            
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**Note:** I used this slider: https://swiperjs.com/demos#slides-per-view

Comment: use breakpoints: https://swiperjs.com/swiper-api#param-breakpoints

Comment: there's even a demo of what you need: https://swiperjs.com/demos/381-ratio-breakpoints/core

Answer (score 0):

You can define a swiper object in which you can apply all the settings you need and then initialize the swiper with it. An example from some old use case of mine is this;

```
const swiperObject = {
  slidesPerView: 'auto',
  spaceBetween: 50,

  scrollbar: {
    el: '.swiper-scrollbar',
    draggable: true,
    snapOnRelease: true,
  },

  breakpoints: {
    0: {
      navigation: {
        enabled: false,
      },
    },

    1024: {
      slidesPerView: 'auto',
      spaceBetween: 130,
      slidesPerGroupAuto: true,
      centerInsufficientSlides: true,

      navigation: {
        enabled: true,
        nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
        prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
      },
    },
  },
};
```

Then, when it is time to initialize your swiper, you just pass the configuration object in;

```
new Swiper(".swiper", swiperObject);
```

You can use these breakpoints and more (just pass whatever values you need), and in each you can change/overwrite the values dictated by the previous ones.

So, in your case, you would use something like;

```
const swiperObject = {
  slidesPerView: 1,
  breakpoints: {
    769: {
       slidesPerView: 3,
       spaceBetween: 30,
    }
  }
}
```